# How do I draw Bitmap on TextureView

Tags: android, bitmap, android-glide, textureview

I'm trying to play video on android with `TextureView`. Regarding video everithing works well. But `MediaPlayer.prepare();` takes some time. So I would like to show some placeholder for that time. I'm trying to do it with Glide like this:

```
public static final Rect rc = new Rect();
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int w, int h) {
    Surface s = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
    Glide.with(mTextureView.getContext())
            .load(thumbUrl)
            .asBitmap()
            .dontAnimate()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(w, h) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                    rc.set(0,0,w,h);
                    Canvas c = mTextureView.lockCanvas(rc);
                    if (c == null)
                        return;
                    c.drawBitmap(resource, 0, 0, null);
                    mTextureView.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            });

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(s);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mMediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
                mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0);
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it does not show any picture. I case of `SurfaceView` we need to call `onDraw` manualy. And SurfaceHolder has been used for this. But `TextureView` does not have `getSurfaceHolder()` method.

What is the right way of doing this ?

UPD: What I figured out is that picture is displayed if I do not set up `MediaPlayer` it means that `MediaPlayer` keeps surface black while it is buffering video. Is it possible to override this behavior somehow ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902114/mediaplayer-cannot-render-to-textureview-after-image-render/